# Javascript - keyup event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hotkeys

I am using [hotkeys plugin](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) to add handlers to key events.
I have made an image slider, where I go through cover images of magazines. 
I have first made a script where the user can go through covers of a magazine, with a click on navigation buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  imagesIndex = 0,
  nextImage = 0,
  loadedImages = [];

  if (typeof images !== 'undefined') {

    preload();

    $('#forward').click(forwardClick);
    $('#back').click(backClick);
  }
});

var preload = function () {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (nextImage < images.length) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = '/imagecache/cover/' + images[nextImage];
        loadedImages[nextImage] = img;
        ++nextImage;
    }
  }
}

var forwardClick = function() {
  imagesIndex++;

  preload();
  $('#back').removeClass('not-allowed');

  if (imagesIndex > (loadedImages.length - 1)) {
      imagesIndex = loadedImages.length - 1;
  }

  if (imagesIndex > (loadedImages.length - 2)) {
      $('#forward').addClass('not-allowed');
  }

  $('#cover-image').attr({"src" : loadedImages[imagesIndex].src, "alt" : name});
}

var backClick = function() {
  imagesIndex--;

  $('#forward').removeClass('not-allowed');

  if (imagesIndex < 0) {
      imagesIndex = 0;
  }

  if (imagesIndex < 1) {
      $('#back').addClass('not-allowed');
  }

  $('#cover-image').attr({"src" : loadedImages[imagesIndex].src, "alt" : name});
}

module.exports.preload = preload;
module.exports.forward = forwardClick;
module.exports.back = backClick;
```

That works fine, I have a selection of magazines, where when a user clicks on one, gets scrolled to a section where the magazine details that a user has clicked on are created. I am dynamically changing that section each time a user clicks on some magazine, and updating the details with the magazine that was clicked. There a user can go through covers of that magazine on click of navigation buttons.
So, each time a user clicks on some new magazine, I am calling this function:

```
var showMagazineDetail = function showMagazineDetail(id, slug, name, summary, issueImage, magazineImage, visiolinkPrefix, page){
    images = [];
    nextImage = 0;
    imagesIndex = 0;
    loadedImages = [];

    ...rest of the code
```

Here I am emptying the `images` and `loadedImages` arrays.
So, this part works fine. The problem I have is with key events.
I have made this script, where I check if the section is in the viewport, and then enable going through the covers of the magazine.

```
var issueImages = require('./issue-images');
var forward = issueImages.forward;
var back = issueImages.back;

$(document).ready(function () {
  var coverImage = $('.magazine-hero');
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var coverVisible = isElementInViewport(coverImage);

    if (coverVisible) {
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'right', forward);
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'left', back);
    }
  };

});


function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  return rect.bottom > rect.height*0.8 &&
        rect.top < ((window.innerHeight*0.7) || (document.documentElement.clientHeight*0.7)) &&
        rect.right > 0 &&
        rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
}
```

The problem is that when I press the key to go to the next cover it goes immediately to the last cover of the magazine.
When I was checking for `imagesIndex` in the console, I could see that on pressing the `right key arrow`, the `index` goes to 12 (which is the last cover of the magazine) immmediately:

> 1  issue-images.js?828c:28 2  issue-images.js?828c:28 3
>   issue-images.js?828c:28 4  issue-images.js?828c:28 5
>   issue-images.js?828c:28 6  issue-images.js?828c:28 7
>   issue-images.js?828c:28 8  issue-images.js?828c:28 9
>   issue-images.js?828c:28 10  issue-images.js?828c:28 11
>   issue-images.js?828c:28 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the jquery doc
"The keydown event is sent to an element when the user presses a key on the keyboard. If the key is kept pressed, the event is sent **every time the operating system repeats the key**."

You go to the last image because the function is called multiple times.

Use the keyup event instead of keydown

```
$(document).on('keyup', null, 'right', forward);
$(document).on('keyup', null, 'left', back);
```

And set your events a single time

```
var issueImages = require('./issue-images');
var forward = issueImages.forward;
var back = issueImages.back;
var eventBinded = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
  var coverImage = $('.magazine-hero');
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var coverVisible = isElementInViewport(coverImage);

    if (coverVisible && !eventBinded ) {
      $(document).on('keydown', null, 'right', forward);
      $(document).on('keydown', null, 'left', back);
      eventBinded = true;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: How can I prevent that, and only have function called once each time a key event occurs? Since I am only pressing the button shortly, and not holding it pressed.

Comment: By using the keyup event instead of keydown.

Comment: It is the same thing with the keyup event. I have tried the keypress as well, but then the functions were not even called.

Comment: Oh it looks like you set your events multiple times in window.onscroll event function

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you very much for your help!